# Bootstrap navbars and centering items

Tags: css, vue.js, navbar, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vue-bootstrap and I've run into an issue, I'm trying to:

- Have my logo on the left
- Contact button on the right
- and Nav items in the middle

The issue is however, as you can see by the image - the navbar items are centering but not with the page width, and instead just the width of the the page if the logo wasn't there. It's quite hard to explain it but here's a screenshot of devtools: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zpOR.png

Here's the code for my navbar:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" class='lx-navbar'>
      <b-navbar-brand href="#">
        <img src='../assets/images/navbar.png' alt="Larkx Logo" height='35px;'>
      </b-navbar-brand>

      <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
      <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
        
        <b-navbar-nav class="mx-auto">
            <b-nav-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :to='item.to'>{{ item.name }}</b-nav-item>
        </b-navbar-nav>

        <b-navbar-nav>
          <b-button class='lx-btn--1'> Contact </b-button>
        </b-navbar-nav>

      </b-collapse>
    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Header',
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Home', to: '/' },
          { id: 2, name: 'GitHub', to: '/GitHub' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Socials', to: '/Socials' },
          { id: 4, name: 'Nova', to: '/Nova' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
.lx-navbar {
  background: transparent; 
  margin-top: .1vw;
}

.nav-link {
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.lx-btn--1 {
  background: none;
  color: #19c9a2;
  border: 2px solid #19c9a2;
  transition: .15s ease-in-out;
}

.lx-btn--1:hover {
  background: #19c9a2;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #19c9a2;
}
</style>
```